# Issue with workbooks.open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open all the workbooks in a certain folder. One of my approaches is shown below. The weird thing is that this (or whatever alternative was the first I tried) used to be working. It always opens the first file found correctly. The second file always throws an Error 1004.

I have also tried the Dir approach and CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec() to enumerate the files (which works) and then looping on the variant array this produces. All of these work on the first file and crash on the second. I have checked the name of the second file before it is presented to Workbooks.Open() and it has the same path (as expected) but the correct and different name.

```
    Private Sub OpenWbsInPath(zPath As String)
            Dim oFSO As Object, oFldr As Object, oFile As Object
            zPath = IIf(Right$(zPath, 1) = "\", zPath, zPath & "\") ' Ensure trailing "\".
            Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   ' This is OK.
            Set oFldr = oFSO.Getfolder(zPath)               ' This OK.    
            For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=oFile, UpdateLinks:=0      ' Error 1004 on 2nd file.
            Next vFile
        End Sub
```

Handling the error does not get me anywhere, as I want all the files open at the same time. I have plenty of memory and a reasonably fast machine.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your code but give this one a go, it adds in the fact it wont open other files only the specified excel files, it also adds 'doevents' to wait for the file to open.

```
    Sub OpenWbsInPath(zPath As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim zPath As String
    Dim targetFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String

    If Right(zPath, 1) = "\" Then
        'carry on as you need the \
    Else
        zPath = zPath & "\"
    End If

    'only get excel files
      myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

    'target workbook
      targetFile = Dir(zPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While targetFile <> ""

          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=zPath & targetFile) 'Set variable equal to opened workbook
          DoEvents 'make sure workbook open before looping

          targetFile = Dir 'get the next files name
      Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try adding DoEvents. I already tried the Dir logic, with the same result. The odd thing is that this is a part of my app that was already working until a day or so ago. Many thanks.

Comment: All the files in the target directory are Excel files!

Comment: I tried DoEvents but unfortunately it made no difference. I also found an old version of this program, and made some minor changes to the code to be identical to the old version, and it still crashes on that same line. In the old version it is working OK!

Comment: SOLVED: in a different post by  chris neilsen  - not a coding issue at all - one of the files was corrupt and would not open!

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler code which works for me. I have number of files in a folder which I want to open all at a time. This is my code looks like:

```
Sub OpenAllFIle()

    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Fname

    InitialFoldr$ = "C:\" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

     xRow = 2

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
        .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
        .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
            Do While xFname$ <> ""
                Ws.Range("A" & xRow).Value = xFname$
                xRow = xRow + 1
                xFname$ = Dir
            Loop
        End If
    End With

For i = 2 To Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Fname = Ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Workbooks.Open (xDirect$ & Fname)
Next i
End Sub
```

Do let me know if that helps.

Comment: I really appreciate this suggestion, but I would need to adapt it a lot to my needs: 
1. I already know which folder the files are in, so I don't need to use the FieDialog, 
2. All the files I want to open are already in a single folder.
3. If I have properly understood your code, you are potentially selecting multiple folders, and making a list of files in Sheet1 of the workbook containing the code,

Comment: then opening your files from this list, which may or may not have come from the same original folder. I have tried something very similar, by making such a list in an array of variant strings. It still crashes on the second workbook in the unique folder I am working with (i only need to work with this single folder).
There is something very mysterious going on here! Thanks all the same!

Comment: The code is for a single folder only.... and it would get your job done. However, if you do not wish to select folder from FileDialogue, there are other way to get your files open in a single go. But in that case you have to put the folder path somewhere in code or cells.

Comment: I wonder whether the second workbook of your is somehow corrupted. Can you open it manually or try running the code after temporarily removing the file from the folder. It might shed some light on the mystery.